# when the CSS styles are applied to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, knockout.js

I use knockout to render a dynamic list, that has as CSS property width auto ( "width: auto") and I need to know ***when this CSS is applied***. 
Is there is an **event to capture when the CSS styles are applied to the DOM**, or an event for the time when the DOM is ready to be visible?

```
 <div style: "width= auto">
  <!-- ko foreach: items -->
        <div class="list-item" data-bind="css: { active: !$parent.isActive() }">
            <a data-bind="text: Label"></a>
        </div>
  <!-- /ko -->
 </div>
```

thanks

Comment: I found an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875128/how-to-tell-when-a-dynamically-created-element-has-rendered?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 2):

The style attribute (in which you should swap out the `=` and the `:` symbols) is applied during the first render and will be visible right away.

The `css` binding is applied when you call `ko.applyBindings`.

If you want to hide stuff until you've applied bindings, you could use a trick like:

```
<div class="hideUntilBind" data-bind="css: { 'hideUntilBind': false }"></div>
```

With css:

```
.hideUntilBind { display: none; }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help, I will think about it. My intention is to display something with CSS, but on depinding of the auto-width size.

Answer (score 2):

Let me summarize the two already mentioned options, and add two other options as well:

1. **Cloaking**: [@user3297291's option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38697464/419956) using a cloak-like trick.
2. **Vanilla JS**: A [vanilla js solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875128/how-to-tell-when-a-dynamically-created-element-has-rendered?answertab=active#tab-top) OP mentioned in a comment to the question.
3. **Fork `css` binding**: Create a [custom binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) based on [the built in css](https://github.com/knockout/knockout/blob/master/src/binding/defaultBindings/css.js) binding that allows for a callback after applying changes. The `css` binding is not that big / difficult, so creating a fork/spinoff seems okay to me.
4. **Foreach / AfterRender**: Using [`afterRender` on the `foreach`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-7-post-processing-or-animating-the-generated-dom-elements) you can link some code to rendering of individual elements, and adjust the DOM / CSS accordingly.