# Change property before window.confirm()

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Here is my code below:

```
<a
  @click="destroy"
  :class="['button', { 'is-loading': deleting }]"
>
  Delete
</a>

data: () => ({
  deleting: false
}),
destroy () {
  this.deleting = true

  if (!confirm('Sure?') {
    this.deleting = false
    return
  }
}
```

As a result a modal dialog displays and `this.deleting is not true` :/

Is it possible to change deleting property before dialog?

Comment: can you make a [mcve]?

Comment: What do you mean with `this.deleting is not true`. At the time `confirm` is called and the modal is show  `this.deleting` is true. But if you expect that the vue component does some different rendering cause you changed  `this.deleting` then no this won't happen, because `confirm` is blocking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the UI hasn't updated by the time the confirmation dialog appears. You could delay the confirmation dialog a bit using `setTimeout(func, 0)` to ensure that the UI has updated.

It should be something similar to:

```
destroy () {
  this.deleting = true

  // Store reference to `this` for access during callback.
  var self = this;

  setTimeout(function() {
      if (!confirm('Sure?') {
        // self - refers to `this` in the outer context.
        self.deleting = false
        return
      }
  }, 0);
}
```

OR

```
destroy () {
  this.deleting = true

  setTimeout(() => {
      if (!confirm('Sure?') {
        this.deleting = false
        return
      }
  }, 0);
}
```

`requestAnimationFrame` might also be a good alternative.

See: [How to tell when a dynamically created element has rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875128/how-to-tell-when-a-dynamically-created-element-has-rendered)

**Note**: I haven't tested this, because you don't have an MCVE in the question.

Comment: The explanation is most likely correct, but the `this` in the timeout callback now refers to the wrong element.

Comment: @t.niese Good catch! Thanks. I will update the answer.

Comment: by the way u can write setTimeout(() => { this... }

Comment: @nrkz Yeah, that would be a preferable alternative in this case.

Answer (score 1):

At the time `confirm` is called and the modal is show `this.deleting` is `true`. But if you expect that the vue component does some different rendering cause you changed `this.deleting` then no this won't happen, because confirm is blocking.

I would suggest to wrap the native dialog handling for `confirm`, `alert`, `prompt` into own function. That not only allows them to be opend/tiggered async, but also gives the possibility to replace them by custom dialog boxes later.

With `await`/`async` and Promises there is a nice way to do this:

**you dialog module**

```
const dlgs = {}

dlgs.confirm = function (message) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(confirm(message))
    },0)
  })
}
```

**your vue component**

```
<a
  @click="destroy"
  :class="['button', { 'is-loading': deleting }]"
>
  Delete
</a>


data: () => ({
  deleting: false
}),
async destroy () {
  this.deleting = true

  if (! await dlgs.confirm('Sure?') {
    this.deleting = false
    return
  }

  // do the deleting
}
```

Having custom dialog boxes that are implemented using html, have the advantage that you can update informations in background while the dialog box is opened.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For me it is over engineering for such things ;) After all i will not use the confirm method