# How to execute function after rendering except "setTimeout()"

Tags: javascript, jquery

## Environment

Jquery2.0.3

## What I want to do

(like chatapp messanger)

select image file and display as preview

↓

submit

↓

delete preview place

## Code

```
async function send() {
    sendMessage(); // send text(omit detail)
    await sendImage(); // send image
    resetAfterSending(); // delete preview display
}

function sendImage() {
    return new Promise(res => {
        messages.append(`
            <div class=".preview-img">
                <img src="${$('.hoge2').find('img').attr('src')}">
            </div>
        `);

        return messages.ready(() => {
            return res();
        });
    });
}

function resetAfterSending() {
    /**
     * if I use hide() instead of remove(), element remains in DOM element(you can see in chrome elements panel)
     * But in this time, I need to delete in DOM element as well
     */
    $('.preview-img').remove();
}
```

## trouble

When I didn't use async/await, resetAfterSendingMessage() was executed and there was no .preview-img element in DOM, so I coudn't even send image data.
That's why I tried to use async/await like code at the top.

But when I tried to change like that ↓ ,image could be sent.

```
function send() {
    sendMessage();
    sendImage(); 
    //**use setTimeout()  !!
    setTimeout(() => {
        resetAfterSending();
    },0);
}
```

I think async/await executes function, but not finish rendering. This causes problem. (I even don't know it's true or not)

If I need to execute function after rendering, I need to use setTimeout() as [**THIS LINK**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15875128/how-to-tell-when-a-dynamically-created-element-has-rendered) says?

If somebody knows the way instead of setTimeout(), plz comment it out here.You know setTimeout() is not kinda cool, hope you get what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Since `sendImage()` returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises), you could use `.then()`

```
sendImage().then(() => resetAfterSending());
```

Comment: "then" executes after finishing function, but not after finishing render right?    I just think so, and unfortunately i didnt find article about that.