# Set width of broadest element to otherwise unrelated HTML block elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Ideal would be a CSS solution. jquery is an option though.

There is a selection `elts` of jquery elements. They have just been created (`let elt = $('<div ..>some content</div>')`) and **not yet been rendered**.

What I would like to achieve, is to determine the maximum width among these
elements and set it to every single one of them. The usual CSS jazz of
`width: n%_of_some_common_parent;` or `width: some_fixed_value em` is not an
option in my case.

Finding no CSS answer, I tried JavaScript. However, being yet unrendered, the following code fails:

```js
let max_width = 0;
elts.each(function() { max_width = Math.max(max_width, $(this).width()); });
console.log(`Maximum width: ${max_width}`);
elts.each(function() { $(this).width(max_width); } );  // << Fail, due to width == 0px.
```

Yields one big `0`.

What actually works, is using a timeout:

```js
setTimeout(function()
{
    elts = $('._common_cls');
    query_common_maximum_width_and_set_it_to_all(elts);
}, 500);  // << 500ms suffice. Edit: Actually 0 does, too. See below.
```

Nice, jumpy, fragile solution. However, what I really want is either

- `elts.on('render', function() { i_am_called_after_all_new_elements_are_rendered(..); })` or, best,
- CSS: `.common_cls { width: calc('max_known_width_in_group')px; }`

How to achieve that?

## Edit - JavaScript solution.

At least in JavaScript the `setTimeout` approach is a valid solution. Turns out `setTimeout(.., 0)` is only evaluated after the current function/rendering stack has completed. This ensures that the timeout callback is triggered only after `width > 0` is available. *Thx to CBroe in the comments below.*

Comment: There is no "render" event, and CSS has no way of  "querying" the widths of unrelated elements.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the "unrelated"? Are they just added in arbitrary positions all over the DOM, or what? Where does the need for a _common_ width come from then, if they are supposed to be "unrelated"?

Comment: [Is there 'element rendered' event?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15875128/1427878)

Comment: CBroe: It is a Bootstrap "table". A common parent is a 'col' holding multiple rows. Within these rows is (among other things) a button. These buttons should receive as width the broadest button's width. I have a function that generates such a row. So the logic is `<div col><div row1><div col>..<button1>..</div></div><div row2><div col>.. <button2>..</div></div>..</div>`

Comment: Then I think you will really have to loop over them in JS and determine the maximum width.

Comment: Yes, boiling that path down, I would need a trigger that is fired when all these elements have finished rendering. My problem is, that this is just one layout of many that I support, and I do not easily want to soften up the approach of having a function that generates such a row, returning it as a new jquery block element.

Comment: The thread I mentioned above discusses some approaches. But I think the setTimeout/ requestAnimationFrame thing should work fine for you here already. With those, it isn't even about trying to anticipate how much time rendering the elements might take (a timeout of 0 should basically also work) - but about creating a "break" in the JavaScript execution, so that control gets handed back to the rendering engine.

Comment: Timeout of 0? Lol! Never thought of that. But yes, it seems to trigger after "the current round of rendering has finished", which is in fact what I want. Thx. Why don't you hack that into an answer. I would accept it, giving you the praise you deserve.

Comment: The zero-second timeout was mentioned in that answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21043017/1427878 over there already, so I think closing this as a duplicate makes more sense here.

Comment: Setting the width of the top-level column element to `width: fit-content;` in CSS and then `.col .row button { width: 100%; }` stretches each button to the width of the largest button in the column.