# jQuery's live without an event?

Tags: jquery, live

I want to do something like the following(hopefully you get the idea):

```
$('.timepickersec').live(function() {
        $(this).jtimepicker();
    });
```

That is,for each new created `.timepickersec` in the future,bind the `jtimepicker` on it.

But the above is not working, does `$.live` has such a feature?

Comment: This a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548479/jquery-live-on-load-event and short answer no this is not possible.

Comment: Well you can bind a custom event using [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and trigger it using [`trigger`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) whenever you create something with class `timepickersec`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are looking for the [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) plugin. Under the hood it will do `setIntervals` to check for new elements. Now you can sometimes also achieve this same effect using `live mousemove` event. In the callback check to see if the element has already been activated - and activate it appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

Other way with event : DOMNodeInserted to detect when a new element is inserted

```
 $(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
      alert('inserted ' + event.target.nodeName + // new node
            ' in ' + event.relatedNode.nodeName); // parent
});
```