# How to get value from each href on the page, with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, href

var href = $('a[target="_blank"]').attr('href');
    $('a[target="_blank"]').attr('title', 'Öppnas i en ny flik; ' + href);

Let's say I have a link in the header.php file with `target="_blank"`. In the donate.php file I have another link with `target="_blank"`. The code I show you above does only take the href value from the link in the header.php file. How do I take the href value in every link I have on the current page?

If I have the mouse cursor over the link in header.php, it will show "Öppnas i en ny flik; http://the-link.nu/". If I have the mouse cursor over the link in donate.php, it will show "Öppnas i en ny flik; http://another-link.nu/".

Any help to fix this problem? :)
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('a[target="_blank"]').each(function() {
    $(this).attr('title', 'Öppnas i en ny flik; ' + $(this).attr('href'));
});
```

You're only getting the first anchor's attribute because **$.attr()** is designed to get just the value from the first matched element. Using **$.each** lets you loop through all of the elements found.

Comment: Additionally, if you're loading your **donate.php** file dynamically, check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548479/jquery-live-on-load-event to update titles as they come in.

Answer (score 1):

use jquery each method:

```
$('a[target="_blank"]').each(
    function() {
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        $(this).attr('title', 'Öppnas i en ny flik; ' + href);
    }
);
```