# re bind/initialize cycle script after partial update

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

Im using the jquery cycle plugin to make some slideshows on my page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('#slideshow').cycle({
    fx:      'fade', 
    speed:    300, 
    timeout:  5000 
  });

 ...
```

But i also want to make some partial update of the div container to make sure these new comments gets into rotation

```
 setInterval(function() {
  $("#update1").load(location.href+" #update1>*","");
  }, 30000);
```

But after doing this the cycle stops working for. I suspect I have to rebind the cycle to an event but which and how I can't figure out

My HTML looks like this

```
   <div id="update1">

        <div id="slideshow" class="slide_container">

        </div>

      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was here

[jquery .live on load event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548479/jquery-live-on-load-event)

Needed to bind the function call to the partial update

```
$("#update1").load(location.href+" #update1>*",function(){
    LoadSlideShow();  
    });
  }, 30000);
```